# How do i create svg box opening animation?

Tags: svg, css-animations, css-transforms

It looks "broken". Transform origin of the right element is out of place. I am trying to make this box "solid", but it scatters.

http://codepen.io/HappyHarlequin/pen/bZWQro

```
svg:hover #right{
    animation: open_right 1s linear infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
svg:hover #left{
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    animation: open_left 1s linear infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
@keyframes open_right{
  0% {

  }

  100% {
    transform-origin:100% 50%;
    transform: rotate(230deg) rotateX(-230deg)

  }

}

@keyframes open_left{
  0% {

  }

  100% {
   transform-origin: 0% 50%;
   transform: rotate(-230deg) rotateX(230deg)

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rotateX()` is a 3D rotation and you can't do 3D transformations on elements inside an SVG.  You can only apply two dimensional transforms to them (rotate, scale, translate etc in X and Y only)

Even if you could do 3D transforms, you are trying to apply a 3D transform to something that is a two dimensional shape drawn to look like it is 3D. So it would not work anyway.

**Possible approaches**

You could:

1. Stick with 2D and use keyframe animation to animate your box flaps. Draw a series of keyframes of your flaps as they open. Then step, or morph, between those shapes.
2. Change your flaps to be HTML elements, such as a `<div>`. Then position them so that they line up with your fake 3D box and have the right amount of perspective.  Then you can apply a 3D rotation to those.
3. Switch to a proper 3D box and animate that.  There are various JS libraries that can help you with that, such as [three.js](http://threejs.org).